# How to display all members in a database that share the same address after searching for a member by name

Tags: php, mysql

php code so far

```
<?php include 'topbit.php';
    if (isset($_POST['address_submitted'])) {
    $given_name = $_POST['address'];
    $find_address_sql = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `LastName` LIKE 
    '%$given_name%' OR `FirstName` LIKE '%$given_name%' ORDER BY `LastName` 
    ASC";
    $find_address_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $find_address_sql);
    $find_address_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($find_address_query);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($find_address_query);
?>
```

I need the code to search the database by first or last names that match the search query, and then the members found from that query have their addresses used to search the database for members that have addresses that same as any members returned by the first query. I have spent ~3 hours on this and haven't gotten anywhere so some help would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide some details about your address fields, and relation to member table.

Comment: Why does `$given_name` equal `$_POST['address']`??

Comment: sorry I forgot to change it in search.php @mulquin

Comment: @CaseyBoyes As a side note, your code contains a serious security bug that will allow anybody to steal or destroy your database. You should look into passing `"%$given_name%"` into a "prepared statement" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after your first query result

```
foreach( $find_address_rs as $key =>$value)
    {
      if(isset($addresses))
      {
        $addresses.=','.$value['address'];
      }
     else
    { 
       $addresses=$value['address'];
     }
       }


     $result_members = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `address` in ('".$addresses."')";

$members  = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $result_members);
$members_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($members);
```

Comment: it gives back: Illegal string offset 'address'

Comment: can you please share your database table and print_r($find_address_rs)